# How can a Thread return a value after finishing its job?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say we have this simple example:

```
public Example extends Thread{

    String temp;    

    public Example(){
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        .
        .
        .
        .
        temp = "a_value";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example th = new Example();
        th.start();
    }

}
```

How can the Thread after finishing its job return me the String temp?

Comment: It should be `th.start()`. And you do implemented one of the ways to return a value from the thread.

Answer (score 67):

Make use of the (relatively) new [`Callable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of Runnable (available in 1.5 and newer versions):

Here is a (simple) example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        final ExecutorService service;
        final Future<String>  task;

        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);        
        task    = service.submit(new Foo());

        try {
            final String str;

            // waits the 10 seconds for the Callable.call to finish.
            str = task.get(); // this raises ExecutionException if thread dies
            System.out.println(str);
        } catch(final InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(final ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        service.shutdownNow();
    }
}

class Foo implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() {
        try {
            // sleep for 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch(final InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: "(relatively) new" Relative to what? It was introduced in a version that has now completed its end of service life period.

Comment: Relative to releases... 1.6 is current, it was released in 1.5.  Compare that with Thread which was there in 1.0... lot's of books that students learn from don't have Callable in it.

Comment: foo is software programmer's version of "Baznga" in BigBang Theory :)

Comment: Great example! Thanks TofuBeer. :)

Comment: @TofuBeer Can you also help in how to give input to thread method call() :-)

Comment: @Mohit you can't, because the API doesn't allow you to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call-- what you can do instead is create member variables in Foo and set them in the constructor and use them later in the call method. eg;  task = service.submit(new Foo(1,"abc"));

Answer (score 12):

Look at [Future](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface javadoc. It has sample usage showing you how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by the Observer pattern.
on finishing the thread notifies all listeners that it's finished and they can retrieve the value (through a getter). Or it can even already send the computed value.

Or you can use a task, see [FutureTask](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), a runnable ( indeed as stated below a Callable ) that returns a result and can throw exceptions.

Comment: I think this isthe Observer pattern is the correct answer. What is the point of having a new Thread if you are going to block the execution waiting for the result anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to swap the solution to use Callable objects then you can use also queues and return the result from the threads that way.
I re-wrote your example like this:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

public class GetResultFromThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Queue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        int expectedResults = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < expectedResults; i++) {
            new Example(queue).start();
        }

        int receivedResults = 0;
        while (receivedResults < expectedResults) {
            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(queue.poll());
                receivedResults++;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

class Example extends Thread {
    private final Queue<String> results;

    public Example(Queue<String> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        results.add("result from thread");
    }
}
```

Note that you shall think of synchronization and concurrency!

Comment: Instead of just clicking the down arrow and saying it is a bad solution it would be nice if you explain why. Thanks

Comment: Actually I this @Martin's solution is very smart, thank you for that

Comment: ["**Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** Multiple threads should not access a `PriorityQueue` instance concurrently if any of the threads modifies the queue. Instead, use the thread-safe `PriorityBlockingQueue` class."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)