# java threading method within object with return value

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I am pretty new to using multithreading, but I want to invoke a method asynchronously (in a separate `Thread`) rather than invoking it synchronously.  The basic idea is that I'm creating a socket server with an object in memory, so for each client I will have to run something like `object.getStuff()` asynchronously.

The two constructs I found were:

1. having the class implement Runnable and threading `this` and
2. declaring a `runnable` class within a method.

Additionally `this` method needs a return value- will it be necessary to use `Executor` and `Callable` to achieve this?  Could someone point me in the right direction for implementing this?

I have tried implement option 2, but this doesn't appear to be processing concurrently:

```
public class Test {
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public Thing getStuff(){

        class Getter implements Callable<Thing>{
            public Thing call(){
                //do collection stuff
                return Thing;
            }
        }

        Callable<Thing> callable = new Getter();
        Future<Thing> future = exec.submit(callable);
        return future.get();   
    }    
}
```

I am instantiating a single test object for the server and calling getStuff() for each client connection.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without your code fragments. Maybe you can find something useful from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148899/returning-value-from-thread

Comment: _I am looking to thread a method calls of an object versus the object itself._  That doesn't mean anything.  Show us code, tell us what you expected your code to do, ask us why it does something else instead.  Or, show us code, tell us why you have doubts about it, ask us if there's a better way.

Comment: How do you know that, "this doesn't appear to be processing concurrently?"  The way I read it, the thread that calls `test.getStuff()` is going to submit its `callable` task, and then it will do _nothing_ until the task completes.  `future.get()` does not return until the task is finished.

Comment: I created an instance of Test and called .getStuff() in succession (I put a timer in the function) and it is performing as you said.  Is there a way to implement this so that method calls to .getStuff() are processed concurrently?  (sorry if these rudimentary, I am only familiar with the basic implementation of using the executor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The two constructs I found were 1) having the class implement Runnable and threading 'this' and 2) declaring a runnable class within a method.

Option (2) probably is better.  Most programs would be improved if they had *more* classes, not fewer.  Each named entity in a program—each package, class, method, whatever—should have just one responsibility.  In your option (1), you are asking the class to do *two* things.

For your option (2), you don't actually have to declare a whole class.  You can either use an *anonymous inner class*, or if you can go with Java8 all the way, you can use a *lambda expression*.  Google for either one to learn more.

> Additionally this method needs a return value.

The classic way, is for the `Runnable` object to return the value through one of its own fields before the thread terminates.  Then the parent thread, can examine the object and get the return value afterward.

> Will it be necessary to use Executor and Callable to achieve this?

Necessary?  A lot of people think that `ExecutorService` is a *Good Thing.*

Sounds like you are creating a server that serves multiple clients.  Do these clients continually connect and disconnect?  The advantage of using a *thread pool* (i.e., `ThreadPoolExecutor`) is that it saves your program from continually creating and destroying threads (e.g., every time a client connects/disconnects).  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  If you have a lot of clients connecting and disconnecting, then using a thread pool could make a big difference in the performance of your server.

Comment: After some testing I couldn't this to work.  I edited the original post with some sample code similar to my implementation.  Guessing it has to do with the executor called within the method?

Answer (score 2):

## Threading Tutorial

The Java tutorial on concurrency has a good section on this. It's at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html. Essentially, you can either implement `Runnable` or `Callable`, or inherit from `Thread`.

## Subclassing Thread

You can write a class, including an anonymous inner class, that extends `Thread`. Instantiate it, then invoke the `start()` method.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("This is a thread");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread m = new MyThread();
    m.start();
  }
}
```

## Implementing Runnable

You can write a class that implements `Runnable`, then wrap an instance in a `Thread` and invoke `start()`. Very much like the previous.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("This is a thread");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
    (new Thread(r)).start();
  }
}
```

## Return Value

`Runnable` doesn't allow for return values. If you need that, you need to implement `Callable` instead. `Callable` looks a lot like `Runnable`, except you override the `call()` method instead of the `run()` method, and you need to give it to an `ExecutorService`.

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
  public Integer call() {
    System.out.println("A thread using Callable<Integer>");
    return 42;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyCallable c = new MyCallable();
    Future<Integer> f = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(c));
    System.out.println("The thread returned: " +
      f.get());
  }
}
```

Comment: OP never mentioned extending the `Thread` class.  Why would you want to put that old-fashioned notion into his/her head?

Comment: Because, @jameslarge, it flows naturally from there to implementing Runnable wrapped in a Thread. Thread, after all, implements Runnable itself. Really, though, they're both old-fashioned. Callable/Executor is the currently fashionable method.

Comment: _it flows naturally..._  The `Thread` class never would have had a public `run()` method if the Java implementors had known back then what they know today.  It also would "flow naturally" if you started by explaining lambda expressions, and then worked your way toward threading from there.

Comment: @jameslarge I do not believe that word means what you think it means :-)

Comment: That's inconceivable!

Answer (score 0):

Creating and managing threads by yourself is generally bad approach.
As you already pointed - use `Executors` utility class to create executor and submit `Callable`s to it.

Comment: Creating your own _thread pool_ is a bad idea because that's re-inventing a wheel, but not every program that needs threads needs a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RunWResult implements Runable{
    private volatile ResultType var;

    //the thread method
    public void run(){
        ...

        //generate a result and save it to var
        var = someResult();

        //notify waiting threads that a result has been generated
        synchronized(this){
            notify();
        }
    }

    public ResultType runWithResult(){
        //run the thread generating a result
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        //wait for t to create a result
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}

        //return the result
        return var;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good start.  The server will handle client threads, but the server itself has objects for lookups to outside sources (the reason for this is that each source has authentication protocols, message formatting, etc.).