# Parallel summation with multithread java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to explain the Join function by calculating in parallel this equation  D= (a-b)+(c-d).
Suppose that I have an equation D= (a-b)+(c-d). How can I do this equation in parallel using three thread one to calculate (a-b), one to calculate (c-d) and the main thread to show the result.  I need to show that the main does not do show the result before that two thread dead.

Comment: Creating three objects of sub class and call run() method it may works @BetterEnglish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Javadoc says, [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) waits until a given thread dies—hence, it's a statement which blocks until a thread has finished computation. Using your equation:

```
// Choose a, b, c, and d.
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
int d = 3;

// Set up an array for the intermediate results.
int[] results = new int[2];

// Create two threads writing the intermediate results.
Thread t0 = new Thread(() -> results[0] = a - b);
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> results[1] = c - d);

// Start both threads.
t0.start();
t1.start();

// Let the main thread wait until both threads are dead.
try {
    t0.join();
    t1.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }

// Sum up the intermediate results and print it.
System.out.println(results[0] + results[1]);
```

Using a simple array to retrieve results from a thread is a bit fishy (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148899/returning-value-from-thread)). However, it's sufficient for this example.

Answer (score 1):

**I am creating Two threads they are paralyzed :**

*They are **t1** and* **t2**;

- Here t1 calculating (a-b)
- t2  is calculating (c-d)

**Here the main() compute the total sum :**

this code may help you:

```
class SumThread extends Thread implements Runnable {
 public SumThread(int a, int b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      sum = 0;
          }

 public void run( ) {
     sum=(a-b);
            } 

 public int getSum( ) {
    return sum;
          }

 private int a, b, sum;

}


public class Sum2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SumThread t1 = new SumThread(1, 2);
    SumThread t2 = new SumThread(3, 4);
    t1.start( );
    t2.start( );

try {
  t1.join( );
  t2.join( );
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
  System.out.println("Interrupted");
}

System.out.printf("The sum %d \n", t1.getSum( )+t2.getSum());
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could do without join using thread pools (`ExecutorService`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Main {
    static int calc(int a, int b, int c, int d) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        var executor = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        var f1 = executor.submit(() -> a - b);
        var f2 = executor.submit(() -> c - d);
        return f1.get() + f2.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println(calc(1, 2, 3, 4));
    }
}
```

... or with a different kind of `join` from the `CompletableFuture` framework (would also run on the Common Pool):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

    static int calc(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        var s1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> a - b).join();
        var s2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> a - b).join();
        return s1 + s2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc(1, 2, 3, 4));
    }
}
```