# Multi-thread catching response of child thread on javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, multithreading

I have a scenario and cant find reasonable answer. So posting the question directly !

Scenario -

1. I make a ajax request and send a file to be uploaded to the server.
2. On server(tomcat), I download the file and start processing it.

I run the **download-file method** on main thread and **process-file method** on new thread since it takes too long for processing and I dont want user to wait so long.

**My Issue** :

The Ajax response will catch the response in call back method for **download-file method**.

My **process-file method** also return the status response which I require to display on front-end when the processing is complete.

But I cannot because Runnable Interface has return type void for its run method.

Question -

1. How can I get result from **process-file method** and send in as response to front-end
2. If I am able to acheive above, how can I catch the response on front end javascript since main thread response will be caught in ajax success method already.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @GhostCat -- Hey thanks for interest !

I am having CSV with 10000 entries, I am required to store each entry in database. These take too much time and I dont want user to wait so long. 

Will these help???

Comment: No. I mean: a piece of code that shows what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You can get result from **process-file method** by using `Callable` along with `ExecutorService`. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148992/1125284). And return to the front end is explaining below.

**Second:** As you do not want to wait user for **process-file method** so that you already return from main thread and you can not get second return by one single request. The following process make you to understand for better and easier solution for this situation.

1. Assign a **id** (e.g. `UUID`) for the **process-file method**. Pass it to the process-file method and return the **id** from **main thread** to front-end if successfully downloaded.
2. Then after processing your file, **store** in DB/wherever you want or put result in a **`Map<id, result>`** where **id** will be the key.
3. In front end you get the **id** for the **process-file method**. You can do call ajax request for certain interval to get the result of this **id** to a different endpoint (e.g. `/file/status/{id}`).
4. In that endpoint for retrieving result, you can get **result** from **Map** by **id** which is key of the Map or if you store in DB then you can easily get by the **id** and return it to front end.
5. In case you can not get result in Map/DB (in case of the **file-processing** not finished yet) you can send **exception** to frontend so that you can send request again after next interval.