# Return value from thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I am trying to receive serial data from Arduino and i want to store the value in a variable how can i do it ?
I tried the code below but it is not storing the value of string in the array element t[0]

or is there a way to store reading from input stream ?

```
final String[] t = new String[1];
t[0]="0";
final Handler handler = new Handler();
stopThread = false;
buffer = new byte[1024];

Thread thread  = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
        {
            try
            {
                int byteCount = inputStream.available();
                if(byteCount > 0)
                {
                    byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                    inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                    final String string=new String(rawBytes,"UTF-8");
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            textView.append(string);
                            t[0]=string;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                stopThread = true;
            }
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
return t[0];
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148992/9441307) might help, it uses callable to return value from the executed threads. 

For more information about callable check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to TMH's answer, if you want to manage threads yourself or suggested code seems too complicated for now, here's a simpler way of using CompletableFuture:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // computation, reading input streams, etc
        Object result = new Object();

        completableFuture.complete(result);
    }
}).start();

// get() will wait until it's completed
Object resultFromThread = completableFuture.get();

// further processing...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better solution will be something like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ResultFromThread {

    public static void main(String... args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return "something";
        });
        String result = cf.get();
    }

}
```

Instead of '**return "something";**' you just need to add anything you want to do.

Another solution is (with handling an exception):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ResultFromThread {

    public static void main(String... args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return "something";//may also throw an exception
        }).handle((result, throwable) -> {
            if(throwable != null) {
                System.err.println(throwable);//do something with exception
            }
            return result;
        });
        String result = cf.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of `t[0]` inside a new Thread which will run asynchronously. So it is possible that `return t[0];` execute before another thread set the value of t[0]. You can use `Thread#join` write the code as below.

```
thread.start();
thread.join();
return t[0];
```

When you call `Thread#join` the parent thread will wait to finish the `Thread` on which you have called the `join` method.
However, there are several mechanisms to do that like `CountDownLatch` and `CyclicBarrier` or `Future` but I think Thread#join is the easy and best suited for your use case.

Comment: Though if the original poster does this with only a single thread, then there really isn't a point to using threads.