# return value from a function running in separate thread

Tags: java

I have this code that allows to execute functions in a separate thread if "Asynch" annotation is present on them. Everything works fine, except for the day when I realized I also have to handle return value for some new functions that I've just added. I could use handlers and message-passing for this, but, due to already built project structure(which is huge and working fine), I can't change the existing functions to work with message passing.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Defining the Asynch interface
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Asynch {}

/**
 * Implementation of the Asynch interface. Every method in our controllers
 * goes through this interceptor. If the Asynch annotation is present,
 * this implementation invokes a new Thread to execute the method. Simple!
 */
public class AsynchInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Method method = invocation.getMethod();
    Annotation[] declaredAnnotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations(); 
    if(declaredAnnotations != null && declaredAnnotations.length > 0) {
      for (Annotation annotation : declaredAnnotations) {
        if(annotation instanceof Asynch) {
          //start the requested task in a new thread and immediately
          //return back control to the caller
          new Thread(invocation.getMethod().getName()) {
            public void execute() {
              invocation.proceed();
            }
          }.start();
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
    return invocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

Now, how can i convert it so that if its something as:

```
@Asynch
public MyClass getFeedback(int clientId){

}

MyClass mResult = getFeedback(12345);
```

"mResult" gets updated with the returned value?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Maybe if you use Callable? like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141235/828193

Comment: Sure, that's the way. Ill chcek the link. Thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, fundamentally. `getFeedback` has to return *something* in a synchronous way - and while in *some* cases you could update the returned object later on, in other cases you clearly couldn't - immutable classes like `String` are obvious examples. You can't change the value of the *variable* `mResult` later... it's quite possibly a local variable, after all. Indeed, by the time the result has been computed the method in which it was used may have completed... using a bogus value.

You're not going to be able to get clean asynchrony by just adding annotations on top of a synchronous language. Ideally, an asynchronous operation should return something like a `Future<T>` to say "at some point later, there'll be a result" - along with ways of finding out what that result is, whether it's been computed or not, whether there was an exception etc. This sort of thing is precisely why `async/await` was added in C# 5 - because you *can't* just do it transparently at the library level, even with AOP. Writing asynchronous code should be a very deliberate decision - not just something which is bolted onto synchronous code via an annotation.

Comment: Thnx for the quick and well guided info. Really thanx. Although I suspected it to be this way, but wanted to make sure. And yes, Future<T> is a way to do :-)