# Return object from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, return

I am wondering if there is a good way to return an object from a running thread.
In my android project (not important for the question) I have this method:

```
public void getFolders()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files.List request = null;

            do 
            {
                try 
                {
                    request = service.files().list();
                    request.setQ("'appdata' in parents");

                    FileList files = request.execute();

                    result.addAll(files.getItems());
                    request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                    request.setPageToken(null);
                }
            } 
            while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
        }   
    });

    t.start();
}
```

This method grabs some data from the internet and store the result in `List<File> result`. That's why I do not want to run it in the UI thread. Now I want to return this List to my main method. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Callable` interface??

Comment: Could be duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148899/returning-value-from-thread or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141158/how-can-a-thread-return-a-value-after-finishing-its-job

Comment: declaring the `List` as an instance variable of the class is one way to get the data from the List

Comment: See the edit in my answer for the right way of using threads in Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Callable<V>
```

A task that returns a result and may throw an exception. Implementors define a single method with no arguments called call.

The `Callable` interface is similar to `Runnable`, in that both are designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by another thread. A `Runnable`, however, does not return a result and cannot throw a checked exception.

[How to use Callable](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-callable.html).

**EDIT:**
Also you should be using [AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) in android for doing background tasks and not create threads of your own.

Comment: Thank you for that! But I have three methods which looks like the above. How should I use it then?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Callable` interface instead of `Runnable` interface to create threads. `Callable` interface offers a `call()` method, which can return an `Object`.

Because you cannot pass a `Callable` into a Thread to execute, you instead use the `ExecutorService` to execute the `Callable` object. The service accepts `Callable` objects to run by way of the `submit()` method:

```
  <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
```

As the method definition shows, submitting a `Callable` object to the `ExecutorService` returns a Future object. The `get()` method of Future will then block until the task is completed.

You can follow the sample on this link and customize it according to your requirement:

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6