# Return a value after thread finish its work

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to implement Observer pattern in java with threads. What I am trying to do is return a value from the new thread.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141158/how-can-a-thread-return-a-value-after-finishing-its-job), someone recommend to use Observer pattern and I want to use it.

I have the following code:

```
/*Observable*/
public class QRExplorer extends Observable implements Runnable {
private String md5;

public String getMD5()
{
    return md5;
}
private void setMD5(String value)
{
    this.md5 = value;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
@Override
public void run() {
 // do some stuff   
 // here I should obtain a string and I want return that
 setMD5("value");
}

}

/*Observer*/

public class Observador implements Observer {

private QRExplorer observado = null;

public Observador(QRExplorer observado)
{
    this.observado = observado;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if(o == observado)
    {
        System.out.println("Something has changed ¬¬: "+observado.getMD5());
    }
}

}

/*Principal class*/
public class MainView extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ThreadFactory{

private RKeyListener listener;
private Webcam camara;
private Executor creador = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(this);
private Observador observador;
private QRExplorer explorer;

/*Nothing relevant*/

private void pCamaraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)  {                                     
    creador.execute(explorer);
} 



@Override
public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    Observable obs = (Observable)t;// but Netbeans tells me: incompatible types: Thead cannot be converted to Observable
    obs.addObserver(observador);
    return t;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 @Override
 public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     explorer = new QRExplorer();   // extends Observable
     observador = new Observador(explorer);   //implements Observer
     explorer.addObserver(observador);
     Thread t = new Thread(r);
     return t;
}
```

Comment: It compiles but not works, because the thread that will be returned it is not the new instance of QRExplorer.

Comment: @Bob why do you use ThreadFactory if you want to control the Runnable ? You can use new Thread(explorer).

Comment: @Bob I supposed you create and execute the thread inside creador.execute(explorer)

Comment: I think I solved my issue. As you suggest I do not use ThreadFactory anymore instead of I modified the QRExplorer class, I added the following method:                                                                                                         `public void setObservable(QRExplorer o)
    {
        this.observado = o;
    }` and inside of 'pCamaraMouseClicked' I put this:                            `Thread t = new Thread(explorer);
 explorer.addObserver(observador);
 observador.setObservable(explorer);
 t.start();`

Comment: ok. Actually you have the setObservable implicitly when you use the constructor Observador(QRExplorer exp)