# How to return value once all thread complete its execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to fetch large
data from SQLite database in xml format, earlier I was doing this on
UI thread bt i was getting ANR and it was takign lot of time to
extract data so I tried this piece of code and this code works fine
but still gives me ANR dialog.

Please suggest better way.

```
    private Map<String, String> getSaleParams()  {


                            final String[] invSaleMasterXML = {""};
                            final String[] invSaleTransactionXML = {""};
                            final String[] invSaleVoucherXML = {""};
                            final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            final DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = ApplicationController.getDatabaseHandler(mContext);

                            Runnable saleMasterRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    invSaleMasterXML[0] =databaseHandler.
                                    getAllInventoryMasterRecords();
                                    params.put("InvSaleMasterXML",
invSaleMasterXML[0]);
                                }
                            };
                            Thread saleMasterThread = new Thread(saleMasterRunnable);

                            Runnable saleTransactionRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                invSaleTransactionXML[0] = databaseHandler.
                                getAllInventoryTransactionRecords();
                                params.put("InvSaleTransactionXML",
                                invSaleTransactionXML[0]);
                                }
                            };
                            Thread saleTransactionThread = new 
                            Thread(saleTransactionRunnable);
                            Runnable saleVoucherRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    invSaleVoucherXML[0] =
                                    databaseHandler.getVoucherTableRecords();
                                    params.put("InvSaleVoucherXML", invSaleVoucherXML[0]);
                                }
                            };
                            Thread saleVoucherThread = new Thread(saleVoucherRunnable);
                            saleMasterThread.start();
                            saleTransactionThread.start();
                            saleVoucherThread.start();
                            params.put("UserID",
ApplicationController.getSessionManager(mContext).getUserId());


                            try {
                                saleMasterThread.join();
                                saleTransactionThread.join();
                                saleVoucherThread.join();
                                return params;
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return params;
                    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a Thread return a value after finishing its job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141158/how-can-a-thread-return-a-value-after-finishing-its-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.join()` still causes the UI thread to wait until the results are loaded. Remove these, and implement a listener-scheme instead. This way, the UI thread is not blocked.

When the data-fetch operation is done, the UI thread gets notified and can update the views. Until then, you can display a loading bar or something like that.

```
Runnable saleVoucherRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // get data...
        Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                // update some views with the data
                View view = findViewById(...);
                view.setText(...);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias bt as you can see on my shared code, I have three methods which are fetching data, i want to make sure all three done with fetching data nd then want to return value.

Comment: @SaurabhG you could just put the fetching-logic of all runnables into one runnable. Or, you implement a 4th runnable, which `.join()`s on the other 3 threads and then posts back the result via `runOnUiThread()`